# UWP GridView in C# with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, uwp

I have a `Grid` where I want to put a `GridView` in every cell of it from the code-behind in the `.xaml.cs`. The problem is that I do not know how to create a `GridView` with a `DataTemplate` to bind stuff in it in C#

```
DataTemplate Template= new DataTemplate();
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.ItemsSource = book;
```

Thats all I have. Help is appreciated

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to put a GridView in every cell of it from the code-behind in the .xaml.cs.

You could make a `DataTemplate` in App.xaml file like follow.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And use it in the code behind.

```
private void SetUpUI()
{
    var gridView = new GridView();
    //DataTemplate usage.
    gridView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)App.Current.Resources["template"];
    gridView.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "fas", "fasd", "fasf" };
    RootLayout.Children.Add(gridView);
}
```